# Fill list from java iterator

Tags: groovy, collections, iterator

I want to fill list with objects from `java.util.Iterator`. There is a simple java-like code in groovy source file.

```
def itr = reader.read()  
List<FooRecord> ret = new ArrayList<FooRecord>()
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    FooRecord rs = itr.next()
    ret.add(rs)
}
```

Is there groovier way to perform copy from `Iterator` to list?

Comment: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#addAll(java.util.Iterator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def ret = []
ret.addAll(reader.read())
```

Thanks to JB Nizet

Answer (score 2):

You can run a for-each on the iterator:

```
itr.each{ret << it}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you thought using a for() instead of a while?, what about instantiating your class before the while? like this?

```
def itr = reader.read()  
List<FooRecord> ret = new ArrayList<FooRecord>()
FooRecord rs = new FooRecord();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
 rs = itr.next()
 ret.add(rs)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def s = '12345'
def List<String> f=s.iterator().collect{it}
```

Answer (score 0):

or just use the `as` keyword in groovy:

```
def myList = itr as List
```

thus the following code:

```
def list1 = [1, 2, 3]
def itr   = list1.iterator()

println  itr.class.name
println  itr instanceof Iterator

def list2 = itr as List

println "list2:       $list2"
println "list2 class: ${list2.class.name}"
```

prints out:

```
java.util.ArrayList$Itr
true
list2:       [1, 2, 3]
list2 class: ArrayList$Itr1_groovyProxy
```